# Optimistic UI and api secrets

Tags: remix.run

Given the framework supports optimistic UI, the server code including api keys and secrets can wind up on client. Should measures be taken when using those within actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions only run server-side, so you can use API keys and secrets safely there.